# Using jquery in html file from boundle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browserify

I bundled jQuery with browserify and I want to verify that its working
for this I put the bundle reference in the script like following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="./src/app.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>

        var $ = require('./src/app.bundle');
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("p").hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

here I got error:
 `require is not defined...` when I remove it I got $ 
`jquery is not defined` , any idea how to overcome this?

before it was like following which works...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to include jquery to fix the `$ jquery is not defined` error.

Comment: isn't that bundled app only works for itself. no exposed variable outside which makes it great.

Comment: @Semi-Friends - so how should I change it to make it work?

Comment: have you tried assigning your function to `window`? and btw. why not just externally include jquery since you're using it the same way?

Comment: @Semi-Friends - can you provide example how as answer?